# What is a less strong word for "proof"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I often make mathematical claims in some of my class. However, at this point, I recognize that anytime I attempt to "prove" something, more often than not there may be a flaw in my proof.

This puts me in the awkward position of writing "Claim" followed by "proof" when in fact, I highly doubt whatever logic I just put forth actually proves my claim.

What is a less strong word for "proof"?

EDIT: example

Claim: 2^.5 is not a rational number

Proof: .....the usual attempt (someone smarter than me can add it if they feel inclined)

It's not that this proof is flawed. But suppose I attempt it and I give an "attempted proof" that happens not to be right. Then my attempt is not a proof whereas the usual proof is a proof because it actually proves the claim whereas mine attempts but fails.

Comment: Support, evidence?

Comment: If you are unsure of the logic that you are putting forth then maybe you can write "Intended logic for claim". Then, after verifying the logic, you can change it to "Proof".

Comment: @EdmDroid That's a good idea! I like that one. something that qualifies it is what i'm looking for. I wanted to say "Draft" but that didn't quite make sense because I obviously submitted a "final draft" even if it's flawed. "Attempted Proof" could work I suppose

Comment: @EdmDroid I also thought there might be like an official term for this, but I guess not.

Comment: Are you looking for *rationale?*

Comment: OP Can you add a sample sentence please, in an EDIT to your question?

Comment: In what way do you claim that the proof of the irrationality of root 5 is flawed?

Comment: ***Rationale***  points to your reasoning or thought process. whether it’s right or not is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you're writing is, as far as you are aware, a proof; it's just that experience leads you to think it might not be correct.

There are two roads you might go down here.

One is to call it a *putative proof*, which is to say that you're putting it forward as a proof but without being certain that it really is one. That would be appropriate if you've written out every step in the logic, but you're worried you've made a mistake.

The other, if you've written out the basic steps but not the full detail (which is likely if you're uncertain), is to call it a *sketch proof* or an *outline proof*; which means that this is the essence of the strategy you would follow if you were to attempt a full proof, but it isn't the full proof itself.

Answer (score 0):

[***Conjecture***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjecture) may be the word you are looking for.

> c :  a proposition (as in mathematics) before it has been proved or disproved

You could also use terms like *justify* or *show that*.

Comment: But the  _proof_ of a theorem is the logical reasoning showing it to be true.